# How to see the actual optimized SQL query in a database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, optimization, jdbc

Databases usually optimize queries before executing them. For a query issued using JDBC or a command line client is it possible to see the actual optimized query that was executed by the database. I am using Oracle Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand - the [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) shows you a summarization of what the optimizer sees, not a defacto query:

```
Rows      Execution Plan
--------  ----------------------------------------------------
      12  SORT AGGREGATE
       2   SORT GROUP BY
   76563    NESTED LOOPS
   76575     NESTED LOOPS
      19      TABLE ACCESS FULL CN_PAYRUNS_ALL
   76570      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID CN_POSTING_DETAILS_ALL
   76570       INDEX RANGE SCAN (object id 178321)
   76563     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID CN_PAYMENT_WORKSHEETS_ALL
11432983      INDEX RANGE SCAN (object id 186024)
```

What decisions the optimizer makes, are based on statistics on the tables involved and any indexes.  Refreshing statistics can dramatically change if things have changed enough.

Comment: To be absolutely precise - DBMS often rewrite queries (by removing obsolete parts, like `WHERE TRUE` OR `WHERE a = 1 AND TRUE` etc). But indeed, I also think that OP just misunderstands the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: What if I am requesting a join in a select query but none of the columns of the joined table are requested and the where clause contains the columns of the join column only for the purpose of performing a join effectively making the join unnecessary. Would the join still be performed?

Comment: "purpose of performing a join effectively making the join unnecessary" -- why do you think so? Even if you don't select any fields from the joined table `INNER JOIN` clause can change the result set. It is not the DBMS business - to think for you: if you don't need a join, just remove it yourself.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: With respect, that's a different question.  But assuming valid syntax, a JOIN is always applied -- the result set reflects that.  If there's no data to support the criteria, you won't get anything.  That's not an optimizer issue - the optimizer EXPLAIN output can only be reviewed to make the query faster.

Comment: @zerkms: actually, Oracle will remove a table from a query if it can guarantee that the result set would be the same without it.

Comment: @Jeffrey: correct. And that would be visible in the output of explain plan